# "You cannot delete the owners of a Web site collection" error while removing site collection admin programmaticaly

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm getting this error: "You cannot delete the owners of a Web site collection" whenever I'm trying to delete a site collection administrator programmatically.  I'm making another user as a primary site collection administrator and then deleting the previous site collection administrator, even then I'm getting this error. Has anyone faced this issue? Can someone please suggest me a solution? Thanks.

Below is the code:
I'm setting the site collection administrator using the below code:

```
SPUser ouser = web.EnsureUser(validSiteAdmins[0]);
site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
site.Owner = ouser;
site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
web.Update();
```

Below is the code to move the previous primary site collection administrator:

```
web.SiteAdministrators.Remove(invalidAdmin);
web.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the user from the site admins before.

```
SPUser invalidAdmin = web.EnsureUser(invalidUserName);
invalidAdmin.IsSiteAdmin = false;
invalidAdmin.Update();
```

Hope this helps.